# Access child node with its own namespace

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml

I have the following xml string:

```
<PagesCreated xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <PageCreated>
        <Appeal>General Appeal</Appeal>
        <Fundraiser xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/GG.Api.Services.Data.Dto.PagesCreated">
            <a:FirstName>Michelle</a:FirstName>
        </Fundraiser>
        <Id>4965523</Id>
    </PageCreated>
</PagesCreated>
```

Which I then process with:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($trimmed_result);
```

I can then access the child nodes of PagesCreated with:

```
 foreach ($xml->PageCreated as $PageCreated)
 {
    die(print_r($PageCreated->children()));
 }
```

My problem is that I cannot access the `<Fundraiser xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/GG.Api.Services.Data.Dto.PagesCreated">` node. I'm presuming that this is because it is the root for that namespace.

How can I access the nodes within the `<Fundraiser>` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to edit XML `<Event>` to get working...

OK this works (FirstName used for example):

```
foreach($xml->xpath('//Fundraiser') as $f) {
 var_export($f->xpath('a:FirstName'));
}
```

[Here is an updated working link, with 3 Fundraisers; special thanks to @IMSoP](https://eval.in/82319)

Comment: Apologies, I have had to remove sensitive data from the xml string, the original does validate.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Is the '//' in relation to the root of the document?

Comment: Yes, `//` means start at the root of the document and find all matches, which will mean this answer won't work with more than one `Fundraiser` node. Instead, you could use just `a:FirstName`, to start looking at the current context, as shown here: https://eval.in/82305

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the namespace prefix. You have to call the `children` method with the ns prefix as parameter. Look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php

In your case:

```
$ns = $PageCreated->getNamespaces(true);
$PageCreated->children($ns['a']);
```

The children method returns then only nodes which have that prefix. All others will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I thought would work, but it doesn't. Echoing $PageCreated->children('a') returns a blank result, print_r produces 'SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 1'.

Comment: This is *nearly* right - the `a` is just a local prefix, and isn't guaranteed to always represent the namespace in future; the best way is using the full namespace identifier, which is its URI: `->children('http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/GG.Api.Services.Data.Dto.PagesCreated')` (you'll probably want to define a variable or constant with that URI in). If you're feeling lazy and don't mind the possibility of things breaking if it changes, you can use the prefix directly with `->children('a', true)`.

Comment: Thank you! I was too fast. Edited my example.